# Array map is giving me an error when trying to call the data in a dynamic render operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, atomicassets

```
function UserTransactionsComponent1() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts'
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setAccounts(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  accounts.map((result) => {
    const { account } = result;
  });

  return <PageLayout>Hi! {account}</PageLayout>;
}

export default UserTransactionsComponent1;
```

I **console.log(accounts)** right before I map it and all the properties are there. The issue is that the **account** in the **acounts.map** is showing greyed out on VSCode. It's not being picked up on the **return**. This is causing me to receive the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**.  What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement is outside the variable (account) scope.

```
function UserTransactionsComponent1() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts"
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setAccounts(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const getAccounts = () => {
    if (accounts)
    return accounts?.map((result) => {
      const { account } = result;
      return account;
    })
  }


  return (
    <PageLayout>
      Hi!{" "}
      {getAccounts()}
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default UserTransactionsComponent1;
```

Comment: how could I keep the map outside of the return?

Comment: @Mooch You can use a function to keep it outside, look to the edit in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your map function is running before your fetch has completed, so accounts is still undefined when you try mapping.

There's a few ways to solve this. One options is just to use .then(). So put your map function inside of .then, inside your useEffect.

```
.then(() => accounts.map( // insert rest of function here ))
```

This tells the code to run the map function only after the fetch completes

Comment: could you specify where in the useEffect? I'm getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

`accounts` is not defined until the fetch is complete, so you need to map it in an effect, which waits for the state of `accounts` to be set:

```
useEffect(() => {
  accounts.map(...);
}, [accounts]);
```

On top of that, when you return, `account` will be `undefined`. You can create a loading screen or something while the data is fetching, then re-render with the data:

```
return (
  <PageLayout>{accounts ? accounts : "Loading..."}</PageLayout>
);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your map function; you're not specifying specifically which account in the array you want; you'll need another state.

Comment: I think you mean useEffect

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin indeed, it was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: would that be within the existing **useEffect** (before **fetchData**? Or would it be outside of that ?

Comment: @Mooch outside the `fetchData`.